# VBA - retrieve the name of an opened workbook

Tags: vba, excel

Here's my problem :

I have a sub in my main file (let's call it mainFile)doing this :

> -Opening a file (the user chooses which file to open)
>
> -Retrieve the name of this file in a variable
>
> -Copy value of a few cells in file1, paste them in mainFile

in order to do that, my code looks something like this :

```
Workbooks.Open file1
fileName = ThisWorkbook.Name
Set source = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("Feuil1")
Set target = Workbooks(mainFile).Sheets("Feuil1")
source.Range("A5:A66").Copy target.Range("T5")
```

but the variable fileName, instead of returning, for instance, "file1.xls", returns "mainFile.xls".

I guess it's because the sub is located in mainFile. But what can I use instead of ThisWorkbook.name ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be doing extra work here that you don't need.  We can set a Workbook variable, and use it directly, instead of accessing it by name.

```
Dim wkbk as Workbook

Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(file1)
Set source = wkbk.Sheets("Feuil1")
Set target = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil1")
source.Range("A5:A66").Copy target.Range("T5")
```

The other option that you have (which is not a good choice, because it can lead to strange and hard to debug errors) is to use `ActiveWorkbook`, which references the displayed workbbok.  In this case, that would be the workbbok you just opened.

Comment: This works perfect, thanks ! I didn't know, neither think about setting the workbook variable.

Answer (score 1):

That's one of the issues when using `This...`

Try this code, instead:

```
Dim NewWB as workbook

Set NewWB = Workbooks.Open file1
fileName = NewWB.Name
Set source = Workbooks(fileName).Sheets("Feuil1")
Set target = Workbooks(mainFile).Sheets("Feuil1")
source.Range("A5:A66").Copy target.Range("T5")
```

Read [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for tips on avoiding the `This...`, `Active...` and `Select...` statements to eliminate these (and other) types of issues.

Comment: I use ThisWorkBook very often - it just refers to the workbook containing the code that's running, which is often the workbook I'm after.

Comment: I'm sure you do, and you've gotten to be reasonably good at it. Both my solution and Degustaf's suggest eliminating the `ThisWorkbook` reference and you seem quite thrilled with his(?) response. I simply went a bit further to offer some reading material on how to avoid this type of issue in the future. It's entirely up to you whether you choose to read it & take action on it.

Comment: Not quite sure who's response I'm meant to be thrilled with.  Yes as you've both offered - there's alternatives to using ThisWorkbook.  I was just trying to clarify what ThisWorkbook actually referred to.  I don't believe anything should _always_ be avoided.  It depends on the situation.